# Shopify 401 Authentication issue Upload

Tags: javascript, upload, shopify, credentials

I've created a private app in the Shopify Admin area. Download and upload work fine in Postman, but from my server, only the download works. When trying to upload data, I receive a 401 status code, and the shop data (categories) remain unchanged.

Can anyone tell me what might be causing this?

Could it be related to outdated SSL certificates, or have I missed something fundamental regarding authentication?

I've attached my code (JavaScript and comments) for reference:

```
// Produces 400 + 401
function uploadCategoriesSFY() {
    var settings = {
        "url": "https://shop123456.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-10/custom_collections.json",
        //"url": "https://110a...:321@shop123456.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-10/custom_collections.json",
        // Also returns a 401
        "method": "POST",
        "timeout": 0,
        "headers": {
            "X-Shopify-Access-Token": "sh.._de1123....",
            //"X-Shopify-Access-Token" produces a 401
            /*
               Fri Feb 16 15:05:05 CET 2024: API RESPONSE: {
               "responseCode": 401,
               "errorResponse": "{errors:[API] Invalid API key or access token (unrecognized login or wrong password)}"
            }
            */
            "Authorization": "Basic 456..",
            /*
            * // Authorization in the header produces a 400
               Fri Feb 16 15:02:30 CET 2024: API RESPONSE: {
               "responseCode": 400,
               "errorResponse": "{errors:{custom_collection:Required parameter missing or invalid}}"
            }
            */
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "data": JSON.stringify({
            "custom_collection": {
                "title": "SSLTEST",
                "body_html": "Description of the collection",
                "sort_order": "manual",
                "template_suffix": "your_template_suffix",
                "published_scope": "web"
            }
        })
    };
}
```

- Try different combinations of my API credentials.
- Even basic Authentication.
- Same results.